# Why doesn't the second value assume its null?

Tags: java

```
if (clicked == 1 )
{
    firstCard=cardAction;
    if (secondCard!=null && firstCard.getValue() == secondCard.getValue()){
        firstCard.setText("");
        secondCard.setText("");
    }
    firstCard.setText (Integer.toString (firstCard.getValue ()));
}
```

I am relatively new to programming but basically this is a memory game so when you click a card, a number will appear and you have to click another card and try to guess to make both numbers the same. This block of code is saying if you click a card once; then the inside will run, and this inside says that if the values of each cards are equal to each other then make the cards blank (remove the numbers). My question is, why is it checking if the cards are equal to each other when you only click it once? Wouldn't it already know that the second card is null if you only click one card?

Comment: You need to tell us what all these variables are, where they come from and where they got their values. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: maybe `firstCard` is null?

Answer (score 1):

The test of secondCard probably is checking for null because there might not be a second card yet. Perhaps if only one card has been selected at the beginning of the game? If secondCard will be null, you have to check for that or accessing its value will cause an error.

But firstCard probably always has a value because you don’t get to this code unless a firstCard has been selected.

Now consider how much easier this code would be to understand with a few comments about what it’s doing.  That’s a good lesson to remember....